# How can I properly save Employee in JSP if Employee have another object in it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Employee Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "SALARY")
private int salary;
```

EmployeeDao with two variable path to save Employee:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void addEmployee(int departmentId, String firstName, String lastName, int salary) {
    Department department = getDepartmentById(departmentId);
    Employee employee = new Employee(department, firstName, lastName, salary);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
}
```

...

MainController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("emp", new Employee());
    List<Department> departments = dao.getAllDepartments();
    model.addAttribute("deps", departments);
    return new ModelAndView("Add");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("emp") Employee employee) {

    System.out.println(employee);
    //dao.addEmployee(employee);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

and addPage.jsp

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/employee/add" />

<form:form modelAttribute="emp" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}" >
    <p>Department : <select><c:forEach var="dep" items="${deps}">

            <option name="department" value="${dep.id}"> ${dep.name}</option>

    </c:forEach></select>
    </p>
    <p>
        First Name : <input size="40px" type="text" name="firstName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Last Name : <input size="40px" type="text" name="lastName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Salary : <input type="text" name="salary" />
    </p>
    <input height="300px" type="submit" value="Add User" />
</form:form>
```

How can I set Department into my Employee from JSP?

Also: I got a REST-POST method that works properly, but I don't know how work with it in JSP.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/employee/{departmentId}/{firstName}/{lastName}/{salary}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public void addEmployee(@PathVariable int departmentId,@PathVariable String firstName,@PathVariable String lastName,@PathVariable int salary) {
    dao.addEmployee(departmentId, firstName, lastName, salary);
    dao.calculateAvgSalaryInDepartment();
}
```

Help, pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing child id you can directly pass object with respective key and save entity.

i.e. replace your select tag with this

```
<select>
    <c:forEach var="dep" items="${deps}">
       <option name="department" value="${dep}"> ${dep.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

**Or**

If you want to do this with just passing primary key of child then used `@InitBinder` with spring Validator to recognize the child.

refer [this example](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-frameworks-webdatabinder/)

**Note:** *In rest method you are adding employee by taking department by departmentId so it is working fine and in your jsp post request you are passing employee entity just with department id not department object*.